# How to define mulitple orWhere queries with Doctrines Query Builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I want to create a query using Doctrines QueryBuilder.

The User can choose the database fields which shall be searched by checking or unchecking checkboxes in an HTML form. That is why `$_POST contains 'filters'` and 'like'.

`$_POST['filters']` looks like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "rack" [1]=> string(5) "shelf" }
```

I'm trying to get the following query work to result in

```
SELECT * FROM `inventories` WHERE (`rack` OR `shelf` LIKE '%01%') AND `checkedOutAt` IS NULL ORDER BY `lastChangedAt`
```

I'm using Doctrine in Version 2.5.5 and PHP in Version 7. My controller looks like this:

```
public function searchAction()
{
    $filters = array();
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $vendors = $em->getRepository('Entities\Vendor')->findAll();

    if ($_POST)
    {
        $filters = $_POST['filters'];
        $like = trim($_POST['like']);
        $inventories = $em
            ->getRepository('Entities\Inventory')
            ->findInventoriesBySearch($like, $filters)
        ;
        $this->addContext('like', $like);
    }
    else
    {
        $inventories = $em
            ->getRepository('Entities\Inventory')
            ->findInventories()
        ;
    }

    $count = count($inventories);

    $this->addContext('filters', $filters);
    $this->addContext('vendors', $vendors);
    $this->addContext('inventories', $inventories);
    $this->addContext('count', $count);
    $this->setTemplate('inventoryAction');
}
```

And the according repository (the "findInventories()" repository function works fine):

```
public function findInventoriesBySearch($like, $filters)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $orExpr = $qb->expr()->orX();

    foreach ($filters as $filter)
    {
        $orExpr->add($qb->expr()->like($filter, $like));
    }

    $qb ->andWhere('i.checkedOutAt is NULL');
    $qb->setParameter('like', '%' . $like . '%');
    $qb->select('i')->where($orExpr)->addOrderBy('i.lastChangedAt', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

When I run the script I receive the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT i
>   WHERE rack LIKE 01 OR shelf LIKE 01 ORDER BY i.lastChangedAt DESC in
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41
>   Stack trace: #0
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(483):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT i WHERE ...') #1
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(971):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('line 0, col 15 ...',
>   Array) #2
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1702):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->AbstractSchemaName() #3
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1557):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->RangeVariableDeclaration() #4
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1292):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->IdentificationVariableDeclaration() in
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on
>   line 63

Comment: Have U checked?

Answer (score 0):

Try check up & change it.

1. (Just, an advice) Don't work with `$_POST`/ request type/ access to it/etc. via "your way". Use typehinted `Request` e.g. :

   ```
   public function searchAction(Request $request){

      if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $filters = $request->request->get('filters');

        //.....
      }else{

      }
   }
   ```
2. Guess, the problem there is:

   ```
   //...
   foreach ($filters as $filter)
   {
      $filter = 'i.'.$filter; // <== 'i.rack','i.shelf', so on
      $orExpr->add($qb->expr()->like($filter, $like));
   }
   ```

Comment: I just tried, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I receive the same error message, except for this part: "SELECT i WHERE i.rack LIKE 01 OR i.shelf LIKE 01 ORDER BY i.lastChangedAt DESC"